# aws-sdk ruby - upload file to s3 with client side encryption

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to encrypt my files before sending to S3 (client side encryption). But the file is not being uploaded correctly. It opens with an error. Please guide what can be the issue.
I am using aws-sdk version 3.

Here is my code:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Encryption::Client.new(encryption_key: Rails.application.secrets.s3_client_key)

bucket_name = "my-bucket"

key = "my_records/record_1.jpg"
File.open('file_path', 'rb') do |file|
   s3.put_object(
     bucket:bucket_name, 
     key:key, 
     body:file
)
end
```

Comment: Share the errors please

Comment: It says "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to view an encrypted file through a browser.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html

With client side encryption you need to decrypt after retrieving the object. A browser cannot do the decryption for you.

If you want the object to be encrypted at rest in S3, you can use the server side S3.

Also It will be encrypted during transit if you use SSL to browser, from there it will get decrypt and browser will show the image.

Hope it helps.